# Django - URL template using forms don't match with urlpattern

Tags: python, regex, django

I am a newbie in Django, though I code in python using Twisted, and I still have a long way to go dealing with this platform. Ihave a problem regarding the use of url templates in forms. I have defined a regex path

```
(url(r'^search/(?P<key>\w*)/$', views.searchKey, name='search'),)
```

in my urls.py. The url path works when I hard code the url path. For example:

```
"/search/potatoes/"
```

But when I use forms to post a search to that path, I always get "/search//". Below is my forms code. What seems to be happening?

```
<form action="{% url 'feeds:search' key %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="key" id="key" />
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you printed out the `key` variable in the template to make sure it actually exists?

Comment: yes Timmy, the problem is I can't seem to pass the value of the text field as my parameter value. It always go to
    "/search//"
whenever I click Filter button. Where do you think had I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've set that as a keyword argument, so I think you'll need to use `{% url 'feeds:search' key='potatoes' %}` or if you have an actual variable there `{% url 'feeds:search' key=key_variable %}`.

Now if you're trying to get the form to submit to that URL you'll need to do some JavaScript on the frontend to get that URL changed based on what's input into the `key` field.

Comment: Hey Josh, I did this
    <form action="{% url 'feeds:search' key=key.value %}" method="post">

it seems that [key.value] is always empty though it is not as I'm also printing the value via javascript alert. Have you any idea why that is my friend? Thank you!

Comment: Add [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and see what's actually being sent to the template.

Comment: Thanks again Josh! You are a great help! :-)
One more question Josh. Why is [key.value] always null or empty everytime submit is clicked? Here is the form code.

    <form action="{% url 'feeds:search' key %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="key" id="key" />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </form>

Comment: @Earvin You need to capture the value on the backend using a the request.POST value. You shouldn't need to do `{{ key.value }}`. Some sample code here: https://gist.github.com/joshkehn/8661501